# Extending fagin’s theorem for #P (for arbitary structure)

Tags: counting-complexity, complexity, descriptive-complexity, finite-model-theory

While i am reading *Descriptive complexity of #P functions (Saluja)* in theorem 1 he state that #FO coincides #P on ordered structures.

This is a corollary from fagin’s theorem. I have read fagin’s theorem in *Libkin - Elements of finite Model theory*. If we have a Polynomial NTM, there is a ESO sentence that describe the existence of an accepting computation path on encoding of a finite structure. Suppose $\exists \vec{X} \phi_{M}(\vec{X})$ is such a sentence for a polynomial NTM $M$. Why we can not conclude:
$$
|\{ \vec{R} : \mathfrak{A} \vDash \phi_{M}(\vec{R}/\vec{X}) \} | = | \text{accepting path of }M(enc(\mathfrak{A})) |
$$

This is only possible if there is a case such that we count a same computation twice. Why with no built-in order in structure this could be happend? How is it possible to choose two distict assignment to second order variables $\vec{X}$ such that the resulting second order sentence describe the same computation path?